# To put two outputs from xquery to html in two different rows

Tags: html, xml, xquery

I am practicing with a simple xml code and I want to extract it to html with xquery statements. What I want in this case is to separate myself into a table in html when $ title has two or more in different rows, since it pulls everything into it.

I pass the xQuery code that gives me an error in the second `<tr>` of Xquery.

```
   <html>
     <body>
      <h1>Listado de compras</h1>
      <table border="1">
       <tr>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Libro</th>
       </tr>
      {
          for $Cliente in doc("Clientes")//Clientes/Cliente
          let $titulo := $Cliente/Libros/Libro/titulo
          let $nombre := $Cliente/nombre_cliente
          order by $Cliente/nombre_cliente
          return
           if (count($titulo)>1)
           then 
            <tr>
                <td>{data($titulo[1])}</td>
                <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>  /*Here gives the error*/
                <td>{data($titulo[2])}</td>
                <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
             </tr>
            else
            <tr>
                <td>{data($titulo)}</td>
                <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>
       }
      </table>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML element tags (direct element constructors) must be separated by commas when used as XQuery expressions (such as inside then `then` clause). Parentheses are also needed for precedence.

Nested elements inside a direct element constructor do not need commas.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Listado de compras</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Cliente</th> <!-- no commas here -->
        <th>Libro</th>
      </tr>
      {
        for $Cliente in doc("Clientes")//Clientes/Cliente
        let $titulo := $Cliente/Libros/Libro/titulo
        let $nombre := $Cliente/nombre_cliente
        order by $Cliente/nombre_cliente
        return
          if (count($titulo)>1)
          then (
            <tr>
              <td>{data($titulo[1])}</td>
              <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>, (: comma needed here :)
            <tr> 
              <td>{data($titulo[2])}</td>
              <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>
          )
          else
            <tr>
              <td>{data($titulo)}</td>
              <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>
       }
     </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the error remains the same with the comma

Comment: This is strange. Which error do you get? oXygen executes this query normally.

Comment: Error:
Stopped at C:/Users/USUARIO.LAPTOP-QGQP1H9N/OneDrive - Florida Centre de Formació Coop.V/DAM/Lenguaje de marcas/Unidad 5 XQuery/ActividadEvaluable/Consultas/HTML1.html/file, 20/22:
[XPST0003] Incomplete 'if' expression.

Comment: This looks like an issue with parentheses. The pair of parentheses surrounding the two `<tr>` constructors is important.

Comment: If instead of $titulo[1] and $titulo[2] I would like to put an elemente that was "$titulo[all]", how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the code with the corrections of Ghislain Fourny and adding a loop for more:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <h1>Listado de compras</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <th>Cliente</th>
       <th>Libro</th>
      </tr>
  {
    for $Cliente in doc("Clientes")//Clientes/Cliente
    let $titulo := $Cliente/Libros/Libro/titulo
    let $nombre := $Cliente/nombre_cliente
    order by $Cliente/nombre_cliente
    return

    if (count($titulo)>1)
    then (

    for $i in (1 to (count($titulo))) 
    return
      <tr>
        <td>{data($titulo[$i])}</td>
        <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
      </tr>

    )
    else
            <tr>
                <td>{data($titulo)}</td>
                <td>{data($nombre)}</td>
            </tr>
  }
</table>
```